# Cron job that saves file

Tags: cron

Is it possible to run a cron job on host that also saves a file to your website directory?  I have an API I download a xml file from hourly. I would like to schedule cron to automate this but I'm not sure if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a cron job to execute an arbitrary script. The script can do whatever you like provided it has the appropriate permissions.

`* * * * * /bin/execute/this/script.sh`

Will run the script `script.sh`

You need to configure the crontab entry appropriately (obviously).

Comment: Okay. So my host has the cron setup panel so I will just set the command line to execute script and save xml to root. I will try it now.

Comment: I don't know enough about your host but I did something similar on Lunarpages' hosting and it seemed to work fine.

Comment: yes--im able to run the php and thexml file is saved without issue--however when running as a cron job--the file doesn exist

Comment: Have you specified the full paths to the XML file? It's probably an environment issue where the script is running with different paths etc

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can schedule a script in cron.
In the script you can add lines to generate the file and to place the file in the location you want.

Note:  Be sure that you have permissions to create a file in that specific location path.